# ipcRenderer.send() function not working inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, electron, setinterval, ipcrenderer

I need explanation and a solution to why the following code isnt working in in my Electron code.

```
const electron = require("electron");
const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;

let seconds = 60;
module.exports = function countdown(){
        setInterval(function () {
            if(seconds == 0){
                seconds = 60;
            }
            seconds--
            console.log(seconds);
            ipcRenderer.send("ticking", seconds)
        },1000)
    }
```

All i am trying to do is just publish an event using the `ipcRenderer.send()` method every second, however i get an `Uncaught Exception` error shown bellow.

`Cannot read property send of undefined at Timeout_onTimeout`

[image]

Comment: did you `import {ipcRenderer} from "electron";`?

Comment: @Estradiaz I am, i have added the few lines that are at the top of my file

Comment: @Estradiaz although, i am using require instead of import, but they do the same thing.

Comment: Can you check if `ipcRenderer.send` works outside of your set interval?

Comment: @Mike yes it does, ive just placed it in button click event and that works